# ORMLite custom data persister with multiple columns

Tags: android, orm, ormlite

Say I have a class called `Person` which is normally persisted into a db table using ORMLite.

Now, I have a member inside that `Person` class called `House`. The `House` class contains 3 properties and is NEVER stored into the database.

What I want is whenever `Person` is persisted I want to store the 3 fields of `House` into the `Person` table into 3 different columns.

So the Person table will have : `{ person_name, person_contact, house_address, house_type, house_date }`.

The last 3 fields will come in from `House` object.

I think I should be using a `DataPersister` on the `House` member variable but does this mean it will write the entire `House` object into ONE column? I want to split it into 3 columns inside the `Person` table. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use another table and add a foreign key to House? What minimum Android version are you targeting?

Comment: I do not want to store House into the db. I have no use of it. Is what I am asking even possible in ormlite?

Comment: I am targeting tablets only so this is Honeycomb.

Comment: You can't simultaneously not store House in the database and store House in the database. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did you read my question at all? I want to store a Person class which will contain 2 columns + 3 columns from House object.

Comment: The logical way to do this is with a second table and a foreign key. OrmLite can handle that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking for is called embedded objects.  All of the fields in the sub-object are stored in the parent object.

Sorry, but right now (12/2012) [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support embedded objects.  It is on the TODO list but no plans are in the way for it.  As @user999717 mentioned, we do support foreign objects that can be automatically refreshed.  This allows you to store the `House` object in another table and ORMLite will query for it when you pull out a `Person`.  Here are the docs for it:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign

Comment: Could you tell is this still true for embedded objects?

Comment: OK, Thanks actually I found out that perfect workaround for this could be storing serializable object in a column instead

Answer (score 7):

Actually a perfect workaround for Serializable objects this could be:

```
@DatabaseField (dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE) 
public Person person;
```

As a result Person stored in a single column as usual primitive variable.

Comment: This is dangerous. If you change the class variables of `Person`, values stored in the database will not be deserialized correctly to the changed class.

Comment: @JasonRobinson yes, users of this method should be aware of this consequence.

Comment: Serialization is actually pretty smart @JasonRobinson.  As long as you don't change the version id (and you should never do so) then serialization handles missing and unknown fields appropriately.

Comment: @Gray I didn't know that, so thanks for pointing out my ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
@DatabaseField (useGetSet = true)
private String personStr; // Dummy

public Person person;
public String getPersonStr(){ person.toString(); }
public void setPersonStr(String personstr){ person = Person(personstr); }
```

Too bad the following doesn't work and you need the extra dummy field:

```
@DatabaseField (dataType = DataType.String, useGetSet = true) 
public Person person;
public String getPerson(){ person.toString(); }
public void setPerson(String personstr){ person = Person(personstr); }
```

You could also use dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE as stated in other answers BUT using custom serialization, which means actually implementing Serializable and handle all possible serialization versions when reading.
Default serialization should NOT be used as u'll end up with messed up DB.